# Where does the "getting weaker" definition of "flagging" come from?

Tags: etymology

I understand that "flagging" means "to get weaker," or "exhuasted and slowed," but I don't understand *why*. I presume it comes from a metaphor of some kind, but I cannot identify its origin. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

The [Online Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=flagging) has it that the meaning you cite derives from old Norse:

> is from Old Norse flaka "to flicker, flutter, hang losse," perhaps
>   imitative of something flapping lazily in the wind. Sense of "go limp,
>   droop, become languid" is first recorded 1610s.

Somewhat speculative, I'm not immediatley able to find or offer anything more definitive.

Answer (score 1):

According to the OED, the verb ***to flag***, comes from Old French ***flaquir*** - to become flaccid. It doesn't seem to make an appearance in English until the sixteenth century.

> Etymology: ? < flag adj.; compare Old French flaquir to become
>   flaccid. But probably there is a mixture with an onomatopoeic
>   formation, expressing the same notion as flap, flack, but implying
>   less energetic movement.
>
> 1540   [implied in: R. Jonas tr. E. Roesslin Byrth of Mankynde i. f.
>   lviv   That her brestes..be neyther to great, softe, hangynge, and
>   flaggynge.

Comment: Ah, So the meaning of flag (v) does NOT derive from a metaphor, like I thought, but comes direct from a word in a parent language. Thanks. After some more research, it also appears that flag (n) might come from flaquir too (in the sense of a flag being something that droops or hangs loose), or it could be a totally unrelated false cognate, from a proto-germanic root for flatness.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the OED, the first uses of the word *flag* meaning *to grow weaker* were applied to birds.

> 3 a. *intransitive.* Of wings: To move feebly or ineffectually in attempting to fly. Of a bird: To move its wings feebly (in early use also *transitive* with *wings* as object); to fly unsteadily or near the ground. *Obsolete.*
>
> 1590   Spenser *Faerie Queene*   My Muse, whose fethers..Doe yet but flagg, and lowly learne to fly.
>
> 1605   B. Jonson *Sejanus*  Croaking Ravens Flag'd up and downe.

This was a natural extension of the earlier definition:

> 1 a. *intransitive.* To hang down; to flap about loosely.

The word was later applied to other kinds of weakening, probably figuratively at first:

> 1665   R. Boyle *Occas. Refl.*  Too commonly our Resolutions flagg with our Joys.